# Error when overlay SharePoint calender with Exchange "The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Ntlm'. The authentication

Tags: sharepoint-online, calendar, sharepoint-calendar, exchange-server, exchange-online

I am working on a SharePoint online team site collection inside Office 365. now i added a sharepoint calendar, then i chose to overlay it with exchnage as follow:-

[image]

where i defined the following values:-

- Outlokk web access URL = `https://mail.****.com/owa/`
- Exchnage web service URL  = `https://mail.****.com/ews/exchange.asmx`

but when i access the sharepoint calender i got this error:-

> The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme
>   'Ntlm'. The authentication header received from the server was
>   'Negotiate,NTLM'. (e8855c9e-6056-5000-892f-f2f4a5b97961)

as follow:-

[image]

so can anyone advice on this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce your issue.

This issue occurs because the ability to use the calendar overlay in a SharePoint Online or SharePoint Server calendar that is retrieved from Exchange Online isn't supported.

Refer to:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2997170/the-http-request-is-unauthorized-error-in-a-sharepoint-calendar

Comment: thanks for the reply, now i already read the above link, but seems the error i am receiving is not 100% similar to the error mentioned inside the link.. or they fall under the same category that `This issue occurs because the ability to use the calendar overlay in a SharePoint Online or SharePoint Server calendar that is retrieved from Exchange Online isn't supported.` ??

Comment: Yes. SharePoint Online doesn't support Calendar overlay with Exchange web service.